# How to use Flurry Analytics in Iphone (Titanium Studio)

Tags: iphone, titanium-mobile

I am new in flurry analytics. Need to add flurry analytics in my Iphone Application.
I didn't get any site to explain flurry analytics for titanium Iphone.

If any one done this already.. please help me..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [appcelerator-flurry-module-for-iphone-ipad-and-android](http://www.softgravity.com/articles/blog/7-appcelerator-flurry-module-for-iphone-ipad-and-android) for both apple and android product.

and this is a module for [flurry for titanium-android at github](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/titanium_flurry/blob/master/android/dist/sg.flurry-android-2.0.zip).